# SQL Update with concatenated data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm keep getting lost in this one and struggling to find the right method. Hopefully someone out there might know of a good way of doing what I want to do. 
I have two tables and I want to update one table using concatenated data from the other where the ids are the same. As an example....

Table1

```
  ItemID       CategoryID
       1                20
       1                30
       1                40
       2                10
       3                40
       3                20
       4                10
       4                20
```

Table2

```
  ItemID        CatIDs
       1
       2
       3
       4
```

I want to update Table2.CatIDs with all the Category IDs from Table1 where the ItemIDs match. It seems straightforward when I write it down like that but after trying Inner Joins, Sub Queries and so on as I've found online, I keep getting "You have errors in your SQL Syntax..."

I want Table2 to look something like

```
   ItemID        CatIDs
        1        20,30,40
        2        10
        3        40,20
        4        10,20
```

I've tried Inner Joins and also sub queries and the closest I've got without an error was this....

```
  UPDATE Table2
  SET Table2.CatIDs = Table2.CatIDs + ", " + 
  (SELECT CategoryID FROM Table1 WHERE Table2.ItemID = Table1.ItemID)
```

But it doesn't seem finished and all it done was update four rows with the same CatIDs and then give me the message
      #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

I'm sure someone out there will be able to see where I'm going wrong and point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't do that! Never, never, never store multiple values in one column!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below by using `group_concat()` you can get the `,` separated list and then join between the tables. But storing comma separated values is never a good idea.

```
update table2 t2
join
(
select ItemID,group_concat(CategoryID) as newcat
from table1 group by ItemID
) tab on t2.ItemID = tab.ItemID        
set t2.CatIDs = tab.newcat
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I see that my sub query wasn't set AS anything. Makes sense. There is a reason why the values are being stored together but the original table is preserved for another script. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: @user3683463, again, it's really bad storing `,` separated values. don't do that if you want to save yourself from future nightmare.

Comment: Do you mean particularly comma separated ones, or just multiple values in general? I could use another character if the former. Not quite got the script working as I want but still working on it. Thanks

Comment: @user3683463, I mean comma separated values.

Answer (score 1):

You should realize that `table1` is the right way to store this information.  It is called a junction or association table.  Sometimes you need to do the concatenation for presentation purposes, but you need to keep the junction table for full flexibility.

You can do what you want using an `update` with `join` and `group by`:

```
  UPDATE Table2 t2 JOIN
         (SELECT t1.ItemId, GROUP_CONCAT(t1.CategoryId SEPARATOR ', ') as cats
          FROM table1 t1
          GROUP BY t1.ItemId
         ) tc
         ON t2.ItemId = tc.ItemId
      SET t2.CatIDs = tc.cats;
```

Comment: Cheers Gordon. Original table is kept for other sql queries, but this particular one has a purpose where we need the concatenation. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be quite working yet. It only populates one categoryID rather then concatenated ones. I can display them okay with a Select query, but when making this an alias and trying to select from that, it doesn't seem to want to play ball. Is there anything in the above code that needs adding to or tweaking? Thanks

Comment: @user3683463 . . . The query looks correct to me.  I can't judge what your select query is doing because I have no idea what it looks like.