# SQL Update table with all corresponding data from another table concatenated?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Running PostgreSQL 12.4. I am trying to accomplish [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080727/sql-update-with-concatenated-data-from-another-table) but the syntax given there doesn't seem to be working on psql, and I could not find another approach.

I have the following data:

```
Table 1

      ID             Trait
       1                X
       1                Y
       1                Z
       2                A
       2                B

Table 2

      ID        Traits, Listed
       1
       2
       3
       4
```

I would like to create the following result:

```
Table 2

      ID        Traits, Listed
       1            X + Y + Z
       2              A + B
```

Concatenating with `+` would be ideal, as some traits have inherent commas.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Your question should stand on its own.  Provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
update table2 
SET traits = agg.t
FROM 
(select id,string_agg(trait, ',') t from table1 group by id) agg
where
table2.id = agg.id;
```

[dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vRJaWYMCRhFqjPmKDRFu4m/1)

> Concatenating with + would be ideal, as some traits have inherent commas.

You can use whatever delimiter you like (just change the second argument to `string_agg`).

Comment: Do not use the same column name traits and subquery alias traits as it might cause ambiguity